# LGPL for closed source software?

Tags: intellectual-property, software, licensing, business

Is there any license that behaves like LGPL as in permitting the user/customer of the software to use/and change the software as they want, but has the following properties:

- Does not allow to open source the code or make it available to a third party in any way
- Does not allow to resell the product directly (but allows to sell products that interact with the software)
- any changes to the code of the product belong to the original author and must be made available to them, and all rights to them belong to the original authors exclusively.
- the authors of the software can not be held accountable for problems arising due to changes made by the license holder
- even though changes have to be made available to the authors of the software, the authors of the software have no obligation to include the changes in the next release

So LGPL, without the General Public, but the license holder is allowed to modify their copy as they want as long as they don't sell it.

Comment: or would what i have described here be more of a GPL, but not public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The copyright holder can licence on whatever terms they like

A licence that allows use only on Tuesdays in months with a “y” in them is a totally valid licence.

Comment: yeah, i am just asking whether someone has had any experiences on examples of how such licenses are formulated, but I guess for a "perfect" solution I'd have to check with a law professional.

Comment: @MartinBraun I'm sure there are plenty of intellectual property lawyers who have experience writing such licenses